# Debug javascript of firefox extension in Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox-addon, firebug, chromebug

I'm trying to debug my firefox extension in Firebug. When there is error in the code, Firebug pauses on the code and I can jump to the code that caused error. The problem is when I want to set breakpoint in the code and trace it, it should theoretically be possible, but I can't find it.

Let's restrict this question to Firebug. I'm not satisfied with Venkman (and solve it elsewhere).

thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Chromebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Chromebug). It's installed alongside Firebug, and it allows you to work with the actual Firefox chrome in addition to just the HTML page.

Answer (score -2):

Go to the Script window and choose the script and set a breakpoint by clicking just to the left of the line number of the chosen script

Comment: The problem is in "choose the script". I can see only scripts from the page, not scripts from my extension.